# My ear application is not deploying to webspher application server?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy the ear application to websphere application server and getting the below issue as:

```
    [3/17/15 18:02:49:392 IST] 00000080 wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl getDeploymentDescriptor An error occurred while processing the deployment descriptor, error message=META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
[3/17/15 18:02:49:811 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml]
[3/17/15 18:02:49:811 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.handleException(AppManagementFactory.java:672)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:811 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:141)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:811 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:91)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.GatherTaskData.<init>(GatherTaskData.java:128)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.controller.DefaultBindingsController.perform(DefaultBindingsController.java:137)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:812 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:813 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:642)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:814 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
[3/17/15 18:02:49:815 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:737)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.isEE5(EARFileImpl.java:1032)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.patchXMIFiles(EARFileImpl.java:1018)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.patchFiles(EARFileImpl.java:1004)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.initializeAfterOpen(ArchiveImpl.java:2513)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:1250)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:461 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:445)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.java:64)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.java:31)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.fullOpenArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:413)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.fullOpenArchive(RootEARFileDescriminatorImpl.java:53)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1599)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1573)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:617)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:402)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:270)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getEarFile(AppInstallHelper.java:215)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfo(AppInstallHelper.java:562)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:462 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:129)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:463 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     ... 43 more
[3/17/15 18:02:50:463 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EJBJarFileImpl.java:359)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.isModuleVersionAtLeast30(EJBJarFileImpl.java:794)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.patchXMIFiles(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1109)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.patchFiles(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1096)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.initializeAfterOpen(ArchiveImpl.java:2513)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:445)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.java:57)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.java:31)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.fullOpenArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:413)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.fullOpenArchive(RootEJBJarDescriminatorImpl.java:52)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:560 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEJBJarFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1631)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.openNestedArchive(EARFileImpl.java:1452)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.openNestedArchive(EARFileImpl.java:1388)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.openNestedArchive(LoadStrategyImpl.java:1461)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.createFile(LoadStrategyImpl.java:492)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.createFile(LoadStrategyImpl.java:377)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.ZipFileLoadStrategyImpl.getFiles(ZipFileLoadStrategyImpl.java:417)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.collectFiles(LoadStrategyImpl.java:961)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ContainerImpl.getFiles(ContainerImpl.java:574)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getFiles(EARFileImpl.java:2693)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:954)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:477)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:561 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:735)
[3/17/15 18:02:50:562 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     ... 61 more
[3/17/15 18:02:50:562 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EMF2DOMAdapterImpl_ERROR_0
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.handleInvalidMultiNodes(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1402)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.findDOMNode(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1389)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.primUpdateMOFFeature(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1572)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.updateMOFFeature(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1992)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.primUpdateMOF(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1010)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.updateMOF(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:986)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.primUpdateMOFMultiFeature(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:489)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.updateMOFRootFeature(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1039)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.primUpdateMOF(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:1006)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.updateMOF(EMF2DOMAdapterImpl.java:986)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.doLoad(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:331)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:633)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.xmltrim.XMLTrimResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(XMLTrimResourceImpl.java:231)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:173)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:259)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.load(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:589)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.getMofResource(LoadStrategyImpl.java:1129)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getMofResource(EJBJarFileImpl.java:1342)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptorResource(ModuleFileImpl.java:257)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.XmlBasedImportStrategyImpl.primLoadDeploymentDescriptor(XmlBasedImportStrategyImpl.java:75)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.java:165)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.java:154)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(EjbJar11ImportStrategyImpl.java:161)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EJBJarFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EJBJarFileImpl.java:350)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     ... 83 more
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml]
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.GatherTaskData.<init>(GatherTaskData.java:133)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.controller.DefaultBindingsController.perform(DefaultBindingsController.java:137)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
[3/17/15 18:02:51:698 IST] 00000080 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
```

I am trying to deploy this from admin console. Before this I tried to deploy from my eclipse blue on server tab, it is not showing any errors in console but not deployed successfully. Could you please let me know how can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like tere is a problem with your `application.xml`: `Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml`

Comment: The same code is working in my server machines. But while deploying in my local machine from My Eclipse Blue, it is not deploying with this error.